# Ionic 2: Cordova Vuforia Plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, vuforia

I am using this https://github.com/mattrayner/cordova-plugin-vuforia Cordova Plugin in order to create an Image Recognation App. Unfortunately, I dont' know how to inlcude the Plugin to my Ionic-App.

I tried this:

```
(<any>window).plugins.VuforiaPlugin.startVuforia();
```

But I am getting the Error:

```
Cannot read property 'VuforiaPlugin' of undefined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try with the default way suggested here https://github.com/mattrayner/cordova-plugin-vuforia#startvuforia---start-your-vuforia-session ?

Comment: Yes, the navigator-Property doesn't even find the VuforiaPlugin-class.

Comment: what do you get when you try it? any error message?

Comment: I get the following Error: **Property 'VuforiaPlugin' does not exist on type 'Navigator'**